# Make a binary tree using lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a binary tree using lists, but it is showing me this error, can you help me with this?

```
class BT:
    def __init__(self, lp , data , rp):
        self.LeftPointer = lp
        self.data = data
        self.RightPointer = rp
        
def insert(x):
    #current_position
    c = 0
    #temporary_position
    t = 0
    while True:
        if dsBT[c].data == None :
            dsBT[c].data = x
            break
        elif x > dsBT[c].data:
            if dsBT[c].RightPointer == 0:
                t = c
                while dsBT[t].data != None :
                    t += 1
                dsBT[t].data = x
                dsBT[c].RightPointer = t
                break
            else:
                c = dsBT[c].RightPointer
        else:
            if dsBT[c].LeftPointer == 0:
                t = c
                while dsBT[t].data != None:
                    t += 1 
                dsBT[t].data = x
                dsBT[c].LeftPointer = t
                break
            else:
                c = dsBT[c].LeftPointer
```

**this part is for printing out the data **

```
    dsBT = []
    for j in range(2):
        dsBT.append(BT( None ,None , None ))
    for h in range(len(dsBT)):
        #video game name
        vgm = input(str("enter the game name:\n"))
        insert(vgm)
    for i in range(len(dsBT)):
        print(dsBT[i].LeftPointer , dsBT[i].data ,dsBT[i].RightPointer)
```

***the error it is showing:***

```
enter the game name:
sarim

enter the game name:
dasr
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\workm\Desktop\Sarim\untitled0.py", line 44, in <module>
    insert(vgm)

  File "C:\Users\workm\Desktop\Sarim\untitled0.py", line 14, in insert
    if dsBT[c].data == None :

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

Comment: You're getting the error because some of your pointers are `None` and therefore don't point to a position in your list.  Why not just set the pointers to the actual nodes rather than list indices?  You don't need to use a list at all for this.

Comment: @Samwise how can I do that? also, the pointers need to be empty so that they can store the location of other data. I'd really appreciate it if u can share your code aswell, thanks

Comment: google "binary tree implementation in Python".  :)